# Как детали заказа order-details.php перенести в заказы orders.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно на странице заказов подробно выводить заказы (без перехода на страницу детали заказа), а пока что сделанно так, что при клике на вкладку заказы, у меня появляется номер заказа, статус и все такое, но мне нужно сразу при клике на заказы, чтобы было видно все заказы с подробной информацией, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я думаю аналогично этому https://wp-kama.ru/id_995/dopolnitelnyie-sortiruemyie-kolonki-u-postov-v-adminke.html

Comment: Сделано так, как есть, не просто так. Если Вы начнёте выводить содержимое всех заказов **портянкой**, да ещё с информацией о покупателе , то Ваш сервер умрёт или будет тормозить. Кроме того, в таком случае на страницу мало что влезет, особенно если заказы содержат по 10-30 товаров. Ваша задумка не оптимальна, хотя есть плагины, которые позволяют выводить дополнительную информацию или управлять заказами в своей табличной форме.